# Rendering my animation loses material colors

Tags: rendering, color

I am brand new to Blender (2.87 - Debian Stable) and have been trying to make a simple animation of objects and text that appears whilst I am talking.  I recorded me talking using OBS and the resultant video is a white screen with a feathered transparent cutout with me in it at the bottom.

I have created a 3D model in which a scene made up of Objects (text and some boxes) I want to appear with the faces in the YZ plane being what I ultimately want to see.  These objects have plenty of depth in the -X direction.  Just in front of all these objects is a plane whose texture is composed of the video of me talking.  I animate my talk by deciding at which frame through my talk I want to particular object to start to appear, and at which point I want it fully appeared, and I key frame a transformation on the X axis to that the box, or text, so it moves through the plane and sits just past it, giving a slightly 3D appearance to my diagram.  I can play my animation and it all plays perfectly.

[image: blender view of model to explain the concept]

But when I come to render it, I get the video playing on the plane, but when the objects appear through the plane, they come out white rather than the color that they clearly are in the model.

[image]

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can someone help.

I am not using the compositor and nodes (other than the compositing the image sequence of me talking on to the plane) because I don't know how in the compositor you specify a node is the output of the camera - there doesn't seem to be one.

Comment: Please add a screen of your issue (render result), Eevee right?

Comment: @vklidu Yes. Eevee. Screen Shot added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered what the problem is.  I had world lighting turned up way too high and set to white.  As a result it dominated, washing all the other color out.  Turned it back down to 1 and changed it to black and all is rendering correctly.

Comment: Great you found issue by your self :)